# Proxy links in Spring boot REST service

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I wanted to get an Idea as to how i would achieve this:

1. I have a 3rd party URL to a downloadable file.
2. I have a Rest Service with a different URL.
3. When a user accesses my REST URL, It dynamically switches the 3rd party  URL in place.

i wanted to achieve this for security purposes.

NOTE: i was thinking of sending a JS script instead, which will initiate the second download.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955777), if it's not what you're looking for, please edit your question with some more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring mvc rest service redirect / forward / proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726082/spring-mvc-rest-service-redirect-forward-proxy)